# React-native: when submitting a text input in android, the word suggestions are not cleared

Tags: android, mobile, react-native, android-softkeyboard, textinput

I have an Android app built with React native.
The app has a TextInput and a submit button.
When typing in the text input, the default keyboard starts suggesting words (not sure how this feature is called - auto complete or predictive text).
When clicking submit, the data is stored and the TextInput is cleared via the "clear()" method of the TextInput. For example:

```
this.refs.textInput.clear();
```

For some reason, the "predictive text" is not cleared after the "clear()" method is called. As a result, when the user start typing again, the predictive text continues from where it stopped and the user has to clear the text input.

Note: the text input is multi-line. Not sure if it has anything to do with the problem.
Here is example for the same issue:
[Example](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-messenger/issues/128)

See attached image for more details:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution:

On submit, I change the keyboard and revert back, like in the following code.

```
this.refs.textInput.setNativeProps({keyboardType:"email-address"});
this.refs.textInput.setNativeProps({keyboardType:"default"});
```