# React Native Text Input Clear Doesn't Clear Text

Tags: react-native

Edit: Upon further inspection it seems that this only happens in Android 6.0.1. Having tried on several devices with 6.0, this was not an issue.

I have a very simple React Native code snippet where I want to clear text in a TextInput. It looks a little bit like this:

```
state = {
  v: ""
};

_changeText = v => {
  this.setState({ v });
};

clear = () => {
  this.textInputRef.clear();
}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.clear}>
        <Text> Clear </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TextInput
        ref={ref => this.textInputRef = ref}
        value={this.state.v}
        onChangeText={this._changeText}
      />

    </View>
  );
}
```

Now the behavior I would expect is for this to leave the text input in focus, and clear the text. This is what happens - however, the moment I start typing something on the keyboard, the text I have previously cleared reappears back in the Text Input. Obviously this sort of persistence of the text isn't really desired.

Have any of you ever encountered this issue? Is it a RN bug or is there any way to avoid this behavior without needing to blur the keyboard?

Here's a little snippet to clarify what I mean: https://snack.expo.io/H1S9b5Mpe.

If you start typing, press clear, then carry on typing, the previously shown text will appear before your newly typed text.

Comment: Did you try clearing the state?

Comment: You can find workaround of this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798584/react-native-when-submitting-a-text-input-in-android-the-word-suggestions-are

Comment: The workaround does work. It is obviously not ideal but we are applying it only for the device with the problem.

Comment: I'm on Android 7.0 running the latest stable version of RN (0.49) and it's still an issue apparently. This workaround is the only thing that works for me (setting autocorrect to false did not work, nor did manually setting the state of the input value to null or an empty string though null vs empty string did behave differently for some reason (still neither were right))

Answer (score 7):

I have just finished struggling with this! Its a severe pain!

What i did to solve this (for now), was set the autocorrect prop of the TextInput to false, it seems like this prevents the keyboard from "maintaining a state"

```
<TextInput 
    autoCorrect={false} 
    ref={component => this.messageInput = component} 
    value={this.state.message} 
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ message: text })}
    placeholder="Type your message here..." />
```

I tried everything else and it seems like this is what worked. Looking forward to a better solution!

BTW: you should also do `this.setState({ message: "" })` so that the value on the input is reset to an empty string.

Comment: This works for me! I was having a headache until I found this solution. Very clever. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I make this code for clearing TextInput in React Native OnSubmitEditing you can check my snack: https://snack.expo.io/@andreh111/clear-textinput-onsubmitediting

Here is the code:

```
state = {
    searchInput:'',
    clearInput:false
}

render(){
    return(
        <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
            <TextInput 
                style={{
                    borderColor:'black',
                    borderWidth:1,
                    width:200,
                    height:50
                }}
                onChangeText={(searchInput)=>this.setState({
                    searchInput
                })}
                value={!this.state.clearInput ? this.state.searchInput : null}
                onSubmitEditing={()=>{
                    this.setState({
                        clearInput:!this.state.clearInput,
                    })
                }}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that it's related to a specific RN version, or as you found out - to a specific OS version. The snippet you have indeed works just fine, can't reproduce this issue on 6.0.0.

Maybe instead of using the `clear` method of `TextInput` you can try a different way to clear the text like so:
`this.setState({v: ""});`. It will ensure that the state is in sync and won't hold the previous value.

Comment: Unfortunately the very same thing happens with setState. It seems to be a very strange issue in that we can reproduce it only on some devices running 6.0.1. We can also reproduce it on a device running 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is the code only for clearing the text. You can add your own logic to save it (mabe in another state variable)

```
   state = {
    typedText:'',
}

render(){
    return(
        <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
            <TextInput 
                style={{
                    borderColor:'black',
                    borderWidth:1,
                    width:200,
                    height:50
                }}
                onChangeText={(typedText)=>this.setState({
                    typedText
                })}
                value={this.state.typedText ===" ? null : this.state.typedText}
                onSubmitEditing={()=>{
                    this.setState({
                        typedText:"",
                    })
                }}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy way clear the  after you submit is :

```
<TextInput
    autoCorrect={false}
    style={styles.form}
    value = {this.state.text}
    placeholder={this.props.p_text}
    onChangeText={this.handleChangeText}
    onSubmitEditing={this.handleSubmitEdit}
</TextInput>
```

and in this.handleSubmitEdit do your logic you want to do and add this line

```
handleSubmitEdit = () => {
    // do your  code
    this.setState({ text: ''});
}
```

This will delete the text in  component